# What does context of the reference mean?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

There is a quote from beginning of the section 3.4.3.2/3 N3797 working draft:

> Given X::m (where X is a user-declared namespace), or given ::m (where
>   X is the global namespace), if S(X, m) is the empty set, the program
>   is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(X, m) has exactly one member, or if the
>   **context of the reference** is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m) is
>   the required set of declarations of m.

What does context of the reference mean in that case?

Comment: "A namespace identifier may provide context (Scope in computer science) to a name, and the terms are sometimes used interchangeably. However, the context of a name may also be provided by other factors, such as the location where it occurs or the syntax of the name."(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Namespace_versus_scope)

Answer (score 1):

The context where "::m" or "X::m" is used to refer to something.

In this particular case, if the code has the form `using ::m` or `using X::m;`, which are *using-declarations*.